# topLevelAwait invalid with babel-loader: 'await' is only allowed within async functions

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, webpack-5

webpack5 supports topLevelAwait, just add the following options:

```js
//webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  //...
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true
  },
};
```

Now we can use top level await happily, like this:

```js
import Test from './Test';

const _Test = await import("./Test");
console.log(_Test);
```

It works well.

But when I add babel-loader it will not work:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

It throws an error:

```js
'await' is only allowed within async functions
```

How can I solve this problem?

I need topLevelAwait and babel-loader.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enable Babel's parsing of top-level await, even if Webpack itself supports it, because Babel has to parse the file long before Webpack does.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await
```

then add it to your Babel config or Webpack config, e.g.

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await'],
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just noting you will need 
  `experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true
  },`
in your config *as well* as the plugin.

Comment: I have all of the bells and whistles in the config (even though I'm aware that topLevelAwait experiment isn't needed to be specified anymore past 5.83, i'm on 5.88), it still doesn't work...